# How to compare custom types in GdScript?

Tags: types, gdscript

I am currently working on my first non-tutorial gdscript project and tried to use an `Area2D` to check if the player gets in interaction-range with items. For this I wanted to use the `on_body_entered` signal of `Area2D`. But if I check the type of body, I always get the base-class `RigidBody2D` and not my derived BaseItem class or the specific further derived class, i.e. HealthPotion (I want to check if it is an enemy or item later).

From some googeling I haven't found good solutions, the "is" keyword doesn't seem to work for custom classes:

```
const itemClass = preload("base_item.gd")

func _on_area_body_entered(body):
  if body is itemClass:
    print("item in range")
  else:
    print(body.get_class()) # prints RigidBody2d
```

If I `print(itemClass.new().get_class())` I still get RigidBody2d, not my custom class. Still it doesn't match and enter the else block.

The only thing working I have found is to create some dummy variable and check with `if "dummy" in body:` but that seems a bit far fetched.

Is there a GOOD way to check the if an instance is of a custom class type?

Answer (score 1):

is there a reason you are preloading your custom class? The whole point of

```
class_name NameOfYourCustomClass extends Area2D
```

Is that you can than reference it by that name: `NameOfYourCustomClass` in your code.

Assuming your class_name of your `base_item.gd` file is `base_item` does:

```
if body is base_item:
```

Deliver the result you expect?

I personally still think you might have some missunderstanding what the signal `body_entered` returns. It will return a `Node2D` or to be more clear a `PhysicsBody2D` (or a `TileMap`) object - or an object that extends these classes like the `RigidBody2D` that you see printed - when it enters the `Area2D` that you registered that signal to. But your custom class is not extending a `PhysicsBody2D` or any of the derived classes like `RigidBody2D`, hence you would never register that event anyway. So if your custom class extends the `Area2D` and want to check whether that object entered an `Area2D` or your custom class the signal would be `area_entered`.

For better help the whole code would be required because its very vague what exactly you want to achieve here.

I hope it will give you some hint in what directions you should do your research anyway. Hopefully you will find a fix.

Best of luck,
KowalewskajA

Comment: I did that before I preloaded it, but after it didn't worked I found that example in the official docs. https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#inheritance

Comment: I just removed the potion instance from the level scene and put it back in, now it just works. No idea what caused this bug. Thanks for trying to help